# Consult mysql select for obtaining the toy most donated to children

Tags: mysql, select, max

From the below database, I have been struggling  a few days now to obtain the toy that has been most donated as a gift to the children. My experience with mysql is limited and my search through this forum and the net so far has not led me to understand what I am doing wrong. Here´s the database with the inserted data :

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS gifts;

CREATE DATABASE gifts ;
USE gifts ;

CREATE TABLE children
 (
      id_children INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      name_child VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      age INT NOT NULL
 ) ;


CREATE TABLE toys 
(
  id_toy INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  name_toy VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  age_adequate INT NOT NULL
) ;


CREATE TABLE gifts
(
  id_children INT NOT NULL  ,
  id_gift INT NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY(id_children, id_gift),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_children)    REFERENCES children(id_children),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_gift) REFERENCES toys(id_toy)
) ;




 INSERT INTO children
 VALUES 
     (1,'Juan Perez',5),
     (2,'Jordi Lopez',8),
     (3,'Marta Santiago',12),
     (4,'Laura Martinez',5),
     (5,'Gerard Laudo', 2) ;





 INSERT INTO toys
 VALUES 
       (1,'Scalextric',12),
       (2,'Barbie',3),
       (3,'Bicicleta',5),
       (4,'Monopoly',12),
       (5,'Casa Feber',1),
       (6,'Palacio princesas',5),
       (7,'Nintendo DS',12),
       (8,'Puzzle',5),
       (9,'Sonajero',1);




 INSERT INTO gifts
 VALUES 

   (1,3),
   (2,3),
   (2,8),
   (3,3),
   (3,7),
   (3,4),
   (4,2),
   (4,8),
   (5,9)
```

**This** is the consult that I am implementing .

```
 select name_toy,max(times_given_as_gift) as max_gift
 from toys t, 

( select id_gift,count(*) as times_given_as_gift from gifts g

group by id_gift ) as aux 

where aux.id_gift = t.id_toy

group by times_given_as_gift
```

**Then** I get this in my query result :

```
  name_toy       max_gift

  Barbie          1
  Puzzle          2
  Bicicleta       3
```

In this case , Bicicleta indeed is the toy that has been donated as a gift the most times, as I have checked it from the table data , but I only want it to appear as a single row in my query result. How could I achieve that?

Any suggestion/note/guidance would be helpful. 
Thanks a priori .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Just add an `order by` and `limit` clause:

```
 select name_toy, ;max(times_given_as_gift) as max_gift
 from toys t join
      (select id_gift, count(*) as times_given_as_gift
       from gifts g
       group by id_gift
      ) aux 
     on aux.id_gift = t.id_toy
 group by times_given_as_gift
 order by max_gift desc
 limit 1;
```

I also "fixed" the query to use proper ANSI-standard `join` syntax.